# The best way to replace SCNNode in AR

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scnnode, scnscene

I am developing an AR app about human anatomy. I setup AR and place detection and everything works fine. I need to change or replace the current model with something else. For example, the first model is the human body and then I need to change it with a button to a skeleton. I tried different ways for example if I change `SCNNode` only it doesn't replace with the exact position. So what is the best way to replace a scene or node in AR? here is my code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

  sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: view.frame)
        sceneView.delegate = self
        ARView.addSubview(sceneView)

        // Create a new scene
        bodyScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/test.dae")!
        bodyNode = bodyScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Cube", recursively: true)

        let scale:Float  = 0.1
        bodyNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: scale, y: scale, z: scale)
        bodyNode.isHidden = true
        sceneView.scene = bodyScene

        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true

        ARView.addSubview(ARGuideView)


        //Foucus
        setupFocusSquare()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Remove the bodyNode, if you want to add any other node in the scene 
By adding this line you can remove bodyNode:

```
bodyNode.removeFromParentNode()
```

And if you want just want to replact the bodyNode then simply declare your bodyNode as global and change reinitialize when you want to **change/replace** it.